# How to make lines smoother in an altair plo?

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

I have the following DataFrame:

```
    {'datum': {78: Timestamp('2019-07-22 00:00:00'),
  116: Timestamp('2020-04-20 00:00:00'),
  31: Timestamp('2018-06-04 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2017-10-30 00:00:00'),
  125: Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'),
  45: Timestamp('2018-10-01 00:00:00'),
  14: Timestamp('2018-01-22 00:00:00'),
  44: Timestamp('2018-09-24 00:00:00'),
  73: Timestamp('2019-06-03 00:00:00'),
  89: Timestamp('2019-10-14 00:00:00'),
  130: Timestamp('2020-08-03 00:00:00'),
  53: Timestamp('2018-11-26 00:00:00'),
  85: Timestamp('2019-09-16 00:00:00'),
  93: Timestamp('2019-11-11 00:00:00'),
  29: Timestamp('2018-05-14 00:00:00'),
  16: Timestamp('2018-02-05 00:00:00'),
  35: Timestamp('2018-07-16 00:00:00'),
  90: Timestamp('2019-10-21 00:00:00'),
  83: Timestamp('2019-09-02 00:00:00'),
  19: Timestamp('2018-02-26 00:00:00'),
  40: Timestamp('2018-08-20 00:00:00'),
  92: Timestamp('2019-11-04 00:00:00'),
  122: Timestamp('2020-06-08 00:00:00'),
  98: Timestamp('2019-12-16 00:00:00'),
  59: Timestamp('2019-01-14 00:00:00'),
  42: Timestamp('2018-09-03 00:00:00'),
  33: Timestamp('2018-06-25 00:00:00'),
  99: Timestamp('2019-12-23 00:00:00'),
  69: Timestamp('2019-05-06 00:00:00'),
  97: Timestamp('2019-12-09 00:00:00'),
  17: Timestamp('2018-02-12 00:00:00'),
  28: Timestamp('2018-05-07 00:00:00'),
  65: Timestamp('2019-03-25 00:00:00'),
  109: Timestamp('2020-03-02 00:00:00'),
  115: Timestamp('2020-04-13 00:00:00'),
  66: Timestamp('2019-04-01 00:00:00'),
  18: Timestamp('2018-02-19 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2017-10-23 00:00:00'),
  111: Timestamp('2020-03-16 00:00:00'),
  39: Timestamp('2018-08-13 00:00:00')},
 'size': {78: 263,
  116: 532,
  31: 151,
  5: 803,
  125: 424,
  45: 161,
  14: 917,
  44: 145,
  73: 175,
  89: 4,
  130: 299,
  53: 643,
  85: 386,
  93: 162,
  29: 56,
  16: 39,
  35: 112,
  90: 421,
  83: 127,
  19: 59,
  40: 125,
  92: 142,
  122: 408,
  98: 609,
  59: 118,
  42: 233,
  33: 395,
  99: 178,
  69: 85,
  97: 537,
  17: 15,
  28: 13,
  65: 50,
  109: 277,
  115: 1008,
  66: 133,
  18: 25,
  4: 23,
  111: 192,
  39: 68}}
```

Whenever I try to plot a line chart with altair with the following code:

```
alt.Chart(dt_pv).mark_line().encode(
    x="yearmonth(datum)",
    y="size").properties(width=800)
```

I get this output [image]

The best way I can describe this is: when the line goes from one point to another, it goes all the way down to the minimum value to then goes up to actual value that should be displayed in this point in time. For example, in May, 2018 the line goes down to X-Axis = 0 (or almost zero) to then go up to something between 300 and 400 hundred in this same point in time.

How can I make this transition between the points in line smoother, so that an actual trend is displayed? By smoother I mean, to use the same example from above, that in the transition from Aprilto May 2018, the line should go directly from something between 100 and 200 (in April) to something between 300 and 400 hundred (in May)

If I try to plot a bar chart:

```
alt.Chart(dt_pv).mark_bar().encode(
    x="yearmonth(datum)",
    y="size").properties(width=800)
```

It works just fine.[image]

So I don't think there is a problem with the data, but with my chart configuration.

Comment: It looks like you have multiple "size" values for some dates.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have multiple `size` values for some dates. If you want a smoother plot, you can aggregate them by computing the `max`, `min`, `mean`, etc. depending on what is appropriate for your visualization:

```python
alt.Chart(dt_pv).mark_line().encode(
    x="yearmonth(datum)",
    y="max(size)").properties(width=800)
```

[image]